# ListView into list

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a wpf window with a ListView controller with bunch of item.

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Can I convert this ListView to a `List<T>` so that I can serialize it in XML file?

I tried this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvUsers.SelectedItems)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in lvUsers.SubItems)
    {
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work cause ListViw doesn't containe SubItem property.

Comment: I should serialize the data binded to the ListView, i.e. whatever is in the ItemsSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize your data, your data got to be serializable. Where and how do you define it? The best way, would be to define an `ObservableCollection<YourClass>` and use it as `ItemsSource` in your `ListView`. Than, if `YourClass` is serializable, you can get data from that data collection, and serialize it.

```
<Window 
x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Serialize</Button>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllMyData}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class YourClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Age { get; set; }
            public string Mail { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<YourClass> AllMyData { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AllMyData = new ObservableCollection<YourClass>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                AllMyData.Add(new YourClass { Name = i.ToString() });
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<YourClass>));
            var subReq = AllMyData.ToList();
            var xml = "";

            using (var sww = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
                {
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
                    xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are not using MVVM, I updated the code. Checked in VS, now is working for sure.